# displaying different symbols for each point within the same factor in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot to show the mean of calculated values within each group (organised by factors), as well as the induvidual points themselves. I have managed to do this successfully, however all the points use the same symbol. I want to have a different symbol for each of the points within each factor, and preferably use the same points in the same order for each factor.

An example version of the kind of graph I am currently making is below, however all the points within the same column use the same symbol.

I have thought about using the row number of the points to define the symbol shape, but I think there are only 25 different shapes available in the default `ggplot2` package, and my real data has more than 25 points, plus I would prefer if the same points were used in each column, to keep the graph looking consistent.

```
Mean_list <- data.frame(Cells = factor(c("Celltype1", "Celltype2", "Celltype3", 
                        "Celltype4"), 
                        levels =c("Celltype1", "Celltype2", "Celltype3", "Celltype4")),
                        Mean = c(mean(c(1, 2, 3)), mean(c(5, 8, 4)), mean(c(9, 8 ,3)), 
                        mean(c(3, 6, 8, 5))))

values_list <- data.frame(Cells2 = rep(c("Celltype1", "Celltype2", "Celltype3", 
                         "Celltype4"), times = c(length(c(1, 2, 3)),
                         length(c(5, 8, 4)), length(c(9, 8 ,3)), 
                         length(c(3, 6, 8, 5)))), 
                         values =  c(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 4, 9, 8, 3, 3, 6, 8, 5))

ggplot() + geom_col(data = Mean_list, aes(Cells, Mean, fill = Cells)) +
  geom_point(data = values_list, aes(Cells2, values))
```

Comment: Given the number of points in each column, I would consider replacing the points altogether with a label (say AA-ZZ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before plotting we may assign a number to each row in within a cell:

```
values_list <- values_list %>% group_by(Cells2) %>% mutate(shape = factor(seq_along(values)))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = Mean_list, aes(Cells, Mean, fill = Cells)) +
  geom_point(data = values_list, aes(Cells2, values, shape = shape))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works well to get a different symbol for each point, but I would prefer to have the symbol be related to the position of the value in the list, rather than it's ranking. 

 i.e. in the example above, "1" in Celltypes1, "5" in Celltypes2, "9" in Celltypes3, and "3" in Celltypes4 all to be the same shape, regardless of their value.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Much simpler than what I was originally trying to do without the dplyr package.